# Are "This answer should be marked as accepted" comments not constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, accepted-answer

Occasionally I come across great answers that aren't marked as accepted. They are commonly accompanied by the comment:

> "This should really be marked as accepted."

<sup>([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python))</sup>

In my opinion, the upvotes on the *answer* itself indicate the quality of the answer, and any commenting to the effect of...

> "This should be accepted"
>
> "This is the better answer"
>
> "This works better than the accepted answer"

... is no better than a longer way of adding this comment:

> "+1"

Which makes upvotes *on said comment* even more ridiculous, does it not?

[image: upvoted comment asking for answer to be accepted]

In most cases, a highly upvoted comment indicates extra information relevant to the answer. This expectation makes comments like those above rather distracting and, dare I say, detract from the quality of the presented answer.

Can you provide a counter-discussion exploring the positive value of such comments? Or should they be flagged "not constructive" without reservation?

Comment: I normally flag these type of comments, as somebody who answers a ton of questions, I get notified for each comment which is annoying

Comment: @ShadowWizard This links to the following: 276099 -> 142733 -> 140256 -> 14994. Maybe it should be edited to that it directly links to 14994.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος you got a point, but I follow the "Find the closest duplicate", even if it's already closed as duplicate by itself. It indeed sometimes results in chains, but I think it's for the best.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, the very definition of duplicate is that a question is the same as another one, and it would theoretically make no difference to link to a *same* question instead. The best practical difference is that you won't have to click, click and then click in order to get to the original one.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος generally I agree, but still, this is something unique to meta sites as far as I see it. Just like we sometimes also close questions of questions which are not exact duplicates, just contain an answer that also answers the question we close.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So, I am not supposed to go all over the chain, right?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος why not? What's the harm? Consider this as walking the path of MSE, full with scenic views. :)